# Cucumber/Capybara test with JavaScript doesn't appear to execute for only one test which also uses ActionCable and Redis

Tags: javascript, redis, selenium-chromedriver, capybara, actioncable

I have a Rails (5.2.3) application to which I'm trying to add a chat feature so the users can communicate with each other. I have not fully implemented the feature, as I am trying to write tests as I go (if I don't know how to write tests for what I'm trying to test, I often do it this way). So far, I have two regions of the relevant page of the application laid out in HTML for the sending and reception of chat messages, JavaScript that runs the rest of the page, JavaScript that is intended to run on page load that makes the regions for the chat feature fill out the correct space of the page, JavaScript that listens to the `textarea` for chats to send, and JavaScript that listens for broadcast chats. The relevant test mimics what I can do at the moment in the development version: type text in the sending `<textarea>`, hit return, and see the message in the `<div>` that holds the chats. The development logs show that the message hits the redis server and are forwarded as expected.

The chat tool test fails. If I open the console in the browser running the tests, I see neither errors nor evidence that the JavaScript on the page is executed for this test (all of the other tests, all of which are tagged `@javascript` execute correctly). If I add enough of a delay, I can see that both of the methods I've employed to send the `enter` key to the `textarea` appear to work (in that the cursor moves), but the expected behavior on the page (that the text is sent to the redis server for broadcast) doesn't occur.

There's no evidence in the test log that the ActionCable server fires up. I have `capybara-chromedriver-logger` installed, but I see no evidence of the logging I would expect.

If there is information missing from my question that you think would be helpful in answering it, please ask.

The CoffeeScript I've written for the chat elements (which executes in development, but not in the test):

```
# Behavior for driving the sizing of the heckle forum window.
#= require_self
#= require common
class ChatWindowDriver
  @setChatWidths: () ->
    curWidth = 0
    (curWidth += $('td[data-node="'+n+'"]').width() for n in ["5", "2", "1", "3", "7"])
    curWidth -= 20 # Because of the margins we want
    $('div[id^="chat"]').each (index, element) =>
      $(element).css("width", curWidth)
    $('textarea#chat-text').each (index, element) =>
      $(element).css("width", curWidth)
    headerHeight = 0
    $('td.chat-header').each (index, element) =>
      headerHeight += $(element).height()
    $('div#chat-header-anchor').css('height', headerHeight)
    receiptHeight = 0
    $('tr.chat-receipt').each (index, element) =>
      receiptHeight += $(element).height()
    $('div#chats-received').css('height', receiptHeight)
    sendingHeight = 0
    $('tr.chat-sending').each (index, element) =>
      sendingHeight += $(element).height()
    $('div#chat-send').css('height', sendingHeight)

  @sendChat: (event) ->
    if event.keyCode is 13 # return/enter => send
      Chats.forum.heckle event.target.value
      event.target.value = ''
      event.preventDefault()

$ ->
  console.log 'can we see this message?'
  ChatWindowDriver.setChatWidths()
  $('#chat-text').on 'keypress', (e) => ChatWindowDriver.sendChat(e)
```

`Gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4)
      actionview (= 5.2.4)
      activejob (= 5.2.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.4)
      actionview (= 5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
    activerecord (5.2.4)
      activemodel (= 5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4)
      activerecord (= 5.2.4)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    backports (3.15.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.13)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.0.1)
    cancancan (3.0.1)
    capybara (3.29.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    capybara-chromedriver-logger (0.2.1)
      capybara
      colorize
    capybara-screenshot (1.0.24)
      capybara (>= 1.0, < 4)
      launchy
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.2)
    coffee-rails (5.0.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    colorize (0.8.1)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.5)
    cucumber (3.1.2)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      cucumber-core (~> 3.2.0)
      cucumber-expressions (~> 6.0.1)
      cucumber-wire (~> 0.0.1)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.3)
      gherkin (~> 5.1.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
      multi_test (>= 0.1.2)
    cucumber-core (3.2.1)
      backports (>= 3.8.0)
      cucumber-tag_expressions (~> 1.1.0)
      gherkin (~> 5.0)
    cucumber-expressions (6.0.1)
    cucumber-rails (2.0.0)
      capybara (>= 2.12, < 4)
      cucumber (>= 3.0.2, < 4)
      mime-types (>= 2.0, < 4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      railties (>= 4.2, < 7)
    cucumber-tag_expressions (1.1.1)
    cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
    daemons (1.3.1)
    database_cleaner (1.7.0)
    delayed_job (4.1.8)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 6.1)
    delayed_job_active_record (4.1.4)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 6.1)
      delayed_job (>= 3.0, < 5)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    docile (1.3.2)
    email_spec (2.2.0)
      htmlentities (~> 4.3.3)
      launchy (~> 2.1)
      mail (~> 2.7)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_bot (5.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    factory_bot_rails (5.1.1)
      factory_bot (~> 5.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
    faker (2.8.1)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 1.8)
    ffi (1.11.3)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    gherkin (5.1.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    guard (2.16.1)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.12, < 2.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-rspec (4.7.3)
      guard (~> 2.1)
      guard-compat (~> 1.1)
      rspec (>= 2.99.0, < 4.0)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    i18n (1.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.9.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (2.3.0)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    lazy_priority_queue (0.1.1)
    libnotify (0.9.4)
      ffi (>= 1.0.11)
    libv8 (3.16.14.19)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.4.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.13)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mime-types (3.3)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2019.1009)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.13.0)
    multi_json (1.14.1)
    multi_test (0.1.2)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.7)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    notiffany (0.1.3)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    pg (1.1.4)
    pry (0.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.1)
    puma (4.3.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    rack (2.0.8)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.4)
      actioncable (= 5.2.4)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4)
      actionview (= 5.2.4)
      activejob (= 5.2.4)
      activemodel (= 5.2.4)
      activerecord (= 5.2.4)
      activestorage (= 5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (5.2.4)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    record_tag_helper (1.0.0)
      actionview (~> 5.x)
    redis (4.1.3)
    ref (2.0.0)
    regexp_parser (1.6.0)
    responders (3.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    rgl (0.5.6)
      lazy_priority_queue (~> 0.1.0)
      stream (~> 0.5.2)
    rspec (3.9.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-core (3.9.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.9.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.9.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-rails (3.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-support (3.9.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    ruby_http_client (3.3.0)
    rubyzip (2.0.0)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    sendgrid-ruby (6.0.0)
      ruby_http_client (~> 3.3.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    shoulda (3.6.0)
      shoulda-context (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
      shoulda-matchers (~> 3.0)
    shoulda-context (1.2.2)
    shoulda-matchers (3.1.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
    simplecov (0.17.1)
      docile (~> 1.1)
      json (>= 1.8, < 3)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.10.0)
    simplecov-html (0.10.2)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (4.0.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    stream (0.5.2)
    therubyracer (0.12.3)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.15)
      ref
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.6)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    webdrivers (4.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt
  byebug
  cancancan
  capybara
  capybara-chromedriver-logger
  capybara-screenshot
  coffee-rails
  cucumber-rails
  daemons
  database_cleaner
  delayed_job_active_record
  email_spec
  factory_bot_rails
  faker
  guard-rspec
  jbuilder
  jquery-rails
  launchy
  libnotify
  listen
  nokogiri
  pg
  puma
  rails (= 5.2.4)
  rb-inotify
  record_tag_helper
  redis
  responders
  rgl
  rspec
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails
  selenium-webdriver
  sendgrid-ruby
  shoulda
  simplecov
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen
  sprockets (>= 4.0)
  sprockets-rails
  therubyracer
  turbolinks
  uglifier
  web-console
  webdrivers

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.3p62

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally one would use the `async` actioncable adapter when testing (not the `redis` adapter) and you'd need to configure actioncable to run in app (in the test environment) - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#in-app - in order for it to start up when Capybara starts the application.

Comment: Having done (I think) the necessary configuration (actioncable adaptor set to `async`, and `config/environments/test.rb` containing ```  config.action_cable.mount_path = '/cable'
  config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```), I still see no evidence on the browser side that a message is sent to the ActionCable server. And I see nothing in the logs indicating that a server has fired up, or even tried to start and failed. Further thoughts?

Comment: It was necessary to precompile the assets for the test environment in order to see the correct behavior in the browser.

Comment: @DerrellDurrett Have you precompiled assets previously? If so Rails can get stuck in a mode where it no longer automatically updates the assets.  In that case you can try something like `RAILS_ENV=development bin/rake assets:clobber` to reset to the normal behavior of automatic updates (adjust RAILS_ENV as necessary)

Comment: I hadn't needed to in testing until recently. Because I use RubyMine I have now set it up to unconditionally precompile assets in running tests, as well as restarting the DelayedJobs workers needed for the chat server.